# Expand and collapse the tableview row

Tags: ios, tableview

I am developing an iOS application.  I have one expandable and collapsed tableview. On click the cell of tableview, the tableview cell expands properly but when I click on a second cell I want first cell to collapse and the second to expand.  This would leave only one cell expanded at a time.

**I am using class HVTableview:-
Code:-**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView expandCell:          (UITableViewCell*)cell withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath;
{
UILabel *detail = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
button.alpha = 0;
button.hidden = NO;

[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    detail.text = @"This is Expand.";
    button.alpha = 1;
    [cell.contentView viewWithTag:7].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14);
}];

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView collapseCell:    (UITableViewCell*)cell withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath;
 {
UILabel *detail = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
button.alpha = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    detail.text = @"This is Collapse.";
    button.alpha = 0;
    [cell.contentView viewWithTag:7].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-3.14);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    button.hidden = YES;
}];


 }
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
 }

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [_cites count];
}
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath isExpanded:    (BOOL)isExpanded;
 {
if (isExpanded) {
    return 150;
   }else
   {
    return 100;
    }

}
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath isExpanded:(BOOL)isExpanded;
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *detail = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(goToTop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
title.text = [_cites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row % 9];
NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString* imageFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", indexPath.row % 9 + 1];
image.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", bundlePath, imageFileName]];


if (indexPath.row %2 ==1)
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.9 green:.9 blue:.9 alpha:1];
else
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.8 green:.8 blue:.8 alpha:1];
if (!isExpanded)
{
    detail.text = @"This is collapse";
    [cell.contentView viewWithTag:7].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    button.hidden = YES;
}
else 
{
    detail.text = @"This is Expand";
    [cell.contentView viewWithTag:7].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14);
    button.hidden = NO;
}


  return cell;
}
```

Comment: do you just want to reduce row height on collapse ?

Comment: No I want to collapse the last item.when click on second cell,I want to expand one cell at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by last item ?

Comment: Suppose you have clicked on first cell, and first cell  or row is expanded. Now i want if i do click on second row or cell from the tableView , i want to collapse the first cell of tableView. Which is not happening

Comment: what are you doing in your `didselectrow` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) collapseExpandButtonTap:(id) sender
{
    UIButton* aButton = (UIButton*)sender; //It's actually a button
    NSIndexPath* aPath = [self indexPathForCellWithButtonTag:aButton.tag]; //Let's assume that you have only one section and button tags directly correspond to rows of your cells.
    //expandedCells is a mutable set declared in your interface section or private class extensiont
    if ([expandedCells containsObject:aPath])
    {
        [expandedCells removeObject:aPath];
    }
    else
    {
        [expandedCells addObject:aPath];
    }
    [myTableView beginEditing];
    [myTableView endEditing]; //Yeah, that old trick to animate cell expand/collapse
}
```

In UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([expandedCells containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        return kExpandedCellHeight; //It's not necessary a constant, though
    }
    else
    {
        return kNormalCellHeigh; //Again not necessary a constant
    }
}
```

Key thing here is to determine if your cell should be expanded/collapsed and return right height in delegate method. So accordingly design your requirements.

Comment: If you want to do it in cell selection then apply the logic in the - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{        //here        }